# asp.net MVC custom routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

Hi I am using this two lines in my code:

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Users", new { command = "Login"}, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "divLoginPopupContent" }, new { id = "loginPopup" }))
{
    /// some html with submit button

    // and also have following:
    <%= Html.ActionLink("Forgot your password", "Login", "Users", new { command = "ForgotPassword" }, null)%>
}
```

and this is the map route i have

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Users",
                "Users/{command}",
                new { controller = "Users", action = "Login" }
            );
```

and this is the controller action:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string command)
     {
          /// some actions
     }
```

but I don'y what I am doing wrong here ... I want ActionLink and BeginForm both to be routed to this controller action.

Comment: Hm.. what kind of error are you facing? I just used snippets of your code and everything looks good.. using actionlink and submit button i'm correctly routed to login action with appropriate commands...

Comment: as i have model in my parameter so it not taking me to that action ...

Comment: and give me this error 

HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answering my own question:

i haven't define another route collection variable i.e. command should be declared, like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Users",
                "Users/{command}",
                new { controller = "Users", action = "Login", 
                command = Parameter.Optional }
            );
```